# How QGraphics framework works?

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5

I'm trying to understand GUI with PyQT. I wrote a monopoly game but I can't get the board right, i'm using QGraphicsLayouts to get the result I want:

[image: Monopoly board]

However what I have with the QGraphics framework is this:

[image: Disappointement]

Here is the code:

```
class Board(QGraphicsView):
   def __init__(self):
      super().__init__()

      self.scene = QGraphicsScene()
      self.board = QGraphicsWidget()
      self.board_layout = QGraphicsGridLayout()

      self.properties = [
         "Free Parking", "Strand", "Fleet Street", "Chance", "Trafalgar Square",
         "Fenchurch Street station", "Leicester Square", "Coventry Street", "Water Works", "Piccadilly", "Go to Jail",
         "Vine Street", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "Regent Street",
         "Marlborough Street", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "Oxford Street",
         "Community Chest", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "Community Chest",
         "Bow Street", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "Bond Street",
         "Marylebine station", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "Liverpool Street station",
         "Northumberland Avenue", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "Chance",
         "Whitehall", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "Park Lane",
         "Electric Company", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "Super Tax",
         "Pall Mall", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "Mayfair",
         "Visit Jail", "Pentonville Road", "Euston Road", "Chance", "The Angel Islington", "King's Cross station",
         "Income Tax", "Whitechapel Road", "Community Chest", "Old Kent Road", "Start"
      ]

      positions = [(i, j) for i in range(11) for j in range(11)]

      for position, name in zip(positions, self.properties):
         if name == "":
            continue

         tile = self.scene.addItem(Tile(name, self.scene))
         self.board_layout.addItem(tile, *position)

      self.board.setLayout(self.board_layout)

      self.scene.addItem(self.board)
      self.setScene(self.scene)

class Tile(QGraphicsWidget):
   def __init__(self, name, scene):
      super().__init__()
      self.name = name
      self.tokens = []
      self.layout = QGraphicsLinearLayout()
      self.layout.setOrientation(Qt.Vertical)
      text = QGraphicsTextItem(self.name)
      self.layout.addItem(text)
      print(self.layout.itemAt(1))
      self.setLayout(self.layout)
```

My final goal is to display the players, and property's properties on the tile to have access to the content of the tiles --> if it is owned, which players are currently on it, the price of rent etc...
However I think that i'm not using the QGraphics framework properly.
Any advice or tips on how to achieve what i want?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not adding the tiles to the layout:

```
        tile = self.scene.addItem(Tile(name, self.scene))
        print(tile)
>>> None
```

`self.scene.addItem()` is not the same as other `scene.add` (such as addRect, addLine, etc) that are convenience functions that return a QGraphicsItem: addItem returns None since the item already exists, so you are trying to add *nothing* to the layout, and that's why they are not aligned as they should.

Just get the tile object reference, and add *that* to the layout; also, there's no need to add it to the scene: since you added them to the `Board` parent item, they will automatically appear as soon as you add that to the scene.

```
         tile = Tile(name, self.scene)
         self.board_layout.addItem(tile, *position)
```

PS: Your example contains a lot of unnecessary code and required some editing to make it actually run and finally get to the issue at hand; please consider editing it to keep it a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and remember to do the same in the future also.

Comment: Yes I put that because it displayed something. Removing it causes an error in the Tile class: `self.layout.addItem(text)
TypeError: addItem(self, QGraphicsLayoutItem): argument 1 has unexpected type 'QGraphicsTextItem'`

Now I understand that I can't add a QGraphicsTextItem but how can I define the layout my Tile otherwise?

Comment: You can create a QGraphicsWidget that works as a "parent" for the text item, then create the QGraphicsTextItem('text', parentGraphicsWidget), then add that parent to the layout.

Comment: I was sure i did that before and it didn't work but now it does apparently and i have something to work with.
Thanks!